# Getting error for the product of items in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take inputs from console and use the numbers in performing calculations. I want to stop receiving items into array when i receive some ref value like"10"(in this case) from console. As soon as i enter 10 in console the array has to be ended and the values in array have to be multiplied. I have tried this as a program but am getting 0 as answer for the product being performed.

```
     public class Scrap {
    private static int i;
    private static double[] as;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        as=new double[100];
        for(i=0;i<as.length;i++)
        {

            as[i]=dscan();
            if(as[i]==10)
                break;
        }
        double d=1;
        for(i=0;i<as.length;i++)
        {

            d=d*as[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Product is :"+(d/10));
    }

    public static double dscan()
    {
    System.out.print(" : ");
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `as=new double[100];` will initialize array with 100 zeros (default value for primitive double) and `as.length` will always return 100 (the size of initialized array) and not the number of valid elements, so if you enter less than 100 values the rest will remain zeros, which will be used for multiplication..

To make it work you either need to count the number of valid elements in a separate variable and then use it restrict your array window or as Matej sugests use a dynamically sized collection.

Answer (score 0):

this code works ... i improved it to use List instead of array , because at start you dont know how many inputs you will have ... if you dont understand anything , just ask ...

```
   public class Scrap {
        private static int i;

    private static ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            double d = dscan();
            if (d != 10) {
                al.add(d);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        double d = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            d = d * al.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Product is :" + (d / 10));
    }

    public static double dscan() {
        System.out.print(" : ");
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
    }

}
```